# HTML file to auto login form

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find a way for a page to redirect you to a third party page with a login form and log in for you. Need to use it on a screen that can access pages but cant input anything to said page.

I've managed to create a html file that takes me to the page;

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        window.onload = function() {
        window.location.href = 'www.URL.com';
        };
        </script>
    </head>

</html>
```

I have also figured out that if I paste the following in to the address field after opening the page it logs me in;

```
javascript:void(document.loginForm.name.value = 'MYUSERNAME');
javascript:void(document.loginForm.password.value = 'MYPASSWORD');
javascript:void(document.loginForm.submit())
```

I have not been able to combine the two though. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is a security feature you can not send javascript code to another page an modify this. _window.location.href_ is like a user opens a certain page in the browser by his/her own. This page has nothing to do with the previous page, your page. Otherwise to modify so, this would be an attac on a vulnerabilty called [Cross-site scripting (XSS) wikipedia].(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the source of the form on the other site and look for the action attribute (probably something like `action="/login/"`)

(also make an note of the method attribute)

Then make a form on your own page with the other sites action like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="http://othersite.com/login/" method="same as other site">
  <input type=hidden name="name" value="MYUSERNAME"/>
  <input type=hidden name="password" value="MYPASSWORD"/>
</form>
```

You can submit the form on page load with

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!

Tried below and it still doesnt work. 

Sorry if a simple syntax error, not my area of expertise.

<html>
      <head>
 <form id="loginForm" action="https://online.tableausoftware.com/auth?destination=%2F/auth/login" 

method="post">
   <input type=hidden name="name" value="myusername"/>
   <input type=hidden name="password" value="mypassword"/>
 </form>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
    };
</script>
      </head>
</html>

Comment: you do need `http://`  here try: `<form id="loginForm" action="http://online.tableausoftware.com/auth?destination=%2F/auth/login" method="post"> <input type=hidden name="username" value="myusername"/> <input type=hidden name="password" value="mypassword"/> </form> <script> window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('loginForm').submit(); }; </script> ` this doesn't log me in but does go to the correct page. "myusername" and "mypassword" must obviously be correct

Comment: the site has a hidden input `<input type="hidden" value="TrZSY2ORhmPe3CLI6qtbZrrClAwyA78KfNZM9mlaz+Y=" name="authenticity_token">` that will make life difficult, you may need to scrape that off with your server and inject it into your form